# Would linux tell me if there was a stack overflow?

Tags: c, memory-leaks, stack-overflow, valgrind

Bear in mind I'm relatively new to C and linux.

For one of my classes I have a project in which we are supposed to find which cities are located in a certain geographical box, we have to use binary search trees though the implementation is up to us. In my particular implementation, when inserting a new element into the tree, I recursively call the insertion function on the appropriate sub-tree.

We've also been told to check our programs using Valgrind, as any memory leaks or errors it would throw would negatively impact our grade. My program runs fine with the cities files we've been given up to 100,000, but at 1,000,000 cities Valgrind throws me over a million errors caused by invalid read/writes, the stack has overflown. It doesn't happen if I run Valgrind with a higher stack size.

When I run the program directly without Valgrind however I get no errors. Would linux tell me if there was a stack overflow? What would be the consequences of such an overflow?

Comment: The memory-management hardware would raise a segfault interrupt.

Comment: Here is an interesting article about stack overflow in Linux. http://www-scf.usc.edu/~csci530l/downloads/stackoverflow_en.pdf

Comment: It is not important *how* or *what* will happen, the stack overflow *will* hit you, maybe now, maybe in the future. Since you are already living on the edge: this is the time to remove the recursion from your program.

Comment: Here is an article about recursion versus loops https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/303242/is-there-anything-that-can-be-done-with-recursion-that-cant-be-done-with-loops

Comment: Avoid recursion if you don't have control over the maximum number of recursive calls.

Comment: Log base 2 of 1000000 is only 20. So you are doing something wrong if that overflows.

Comment: I do realize that if it has the potential to overflow at all, the design is faulty, I was just wondering

Comment: Questions about stack overflow on stackoverflow must get an upvote by default ;)

Comment: joop "it is not important how or what will happen" Pardon me? Of course it's important.

I do realize that if it has the potential to overflow at all, the design is faulty, I like the suggestion of 4386427 as it just makes sense.

Thank you RichardChambers for the articles, very helpful

stark as of now the tree is not self-balancing, and the first city to be inserted aka the root is in the middle of the map with a majority of them being in the upper right and having a larger z score so it's entirely possible my tree goes as deep as a few thousands. It needs to be worked on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Would linux tell me if there was a stack overflow?

No, Linux doesn't care if you overflow your stack. However, it does make some attempt to ensure that the memory addresses beyond the end of the stack are unmapped memory, so that a stock overflow will probably segfault. (That depends on the size of each function's stack frame; allocating large arrays on the stack can produce other as symptoms if you are  unlucky.)

The C runtime environment probably won't tell you, either, because it would require inserting extra code, which would slow down execution, and then programmers who had taken care to ensure that their stacks won't overflow would complain about having to pay the cost of protecting your code against your bugs. That might sound harsh, but it is basically the C design philosophy; if you don't like it, there are other languages. However, some compilers do allow you to request that extra code be inserted (with GCC, see the `-fstack-check` option; also see `-fstack-limit-*` and `-fsplit-stack`.)

Answer (score 2):

Why not test it?
With the following Program, i get sometimes a `SIGSEGV` and sometimes not:

```
#include <stdint.h>

uint64_t pos=261950;

int main(void)
  {
    volatile int a; //just some variables to use the stack
    volatile int b; //and avoid too much optimizations
    a=b; b=a;       
    if(pos) 
      {   
        pos--;
        main();
      }   
    return 0;
  }
```

Valgrind shows a error in all my tests. The value 261950 was found with testing, and should most likely be different on a other installation.

This was tested on GNU/Linux AMD64, Debian 8, without any special settings (i did not disable anything like ASLR or stack smashing protection). The build command was:

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra 001.c
```

When the variable `pos` is bigger, i see always a `SIGSEGV`-message.

Of course, here nothing bad happen, but you can not be sure how it end up in a more complex program, so avoid a uncontrolled recursion deep.